# adding constraints to system of nonlinear equations

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

This is my first question on stackoverflow. Sorry if it is a bit clumsy.

I am trying to solve a static equilibrium describing a beam in a layered soil. In terms of forces acting on the beam, there is some external force, and there is the reaction of the soil to that force. The action and reaction obviously have to balance out. The reaction is the sum of forces from the soil integrated over the different layers. The soil responds non-linearly as a function of displacement.  Basically, this particular equilibrium is a scalar because it's just the sum of reaction = action.

On the other hand, the internal forces within the beam also have to balance with the local force acting on the beam element in question. Let's say we have 40 such elements. So the problem I face in a nutshell is the following:

I need to find the root of F1(x1,x2,...x40), with x1,x2...x40 describing the displacement of the pile in the soil.  I pass and initial guess for the displacement, and Fsolve comes back with a vector length 40 which gives F1 = [0,0...0].. So this basically balances the internal forces with the local force on the beam (actually the curvature with moment).

The problem is I cannot seem to add an additional constraint which is the global equilibrium that I described above because that violates the condition in fsolve that the output vector length has to equal the input vector length. I cannot seem to add such constraint within Fsolve. I have also gone the way of optimize where you can add constraints, but that doesn't work because it optimizes a scalar, and does not work with vector roots.

Perhaps I just missed something stupid, but I've scoured stackoverflow in vain a few days. I can probably solve it with differential equation solvers but i don't want to go that way for various reasons if I can avoid it. 
Anything to give me a new angle would help! Brand new to python, so I much appreciate all the helpful solutions I've read so far even if it didn't quite get me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, we have n equations and n variables, i.e. a square system. If the solution is not unique, it means that your equations are not independent. When adding additional constraints, you no longer can use a square system solver. However, it is quite possible to use a nonlinear optimization solver. E.g. we can write:

```
 min 0
 subject to 
      F(x) = 0   (n equations) 
      G(x) = 0   (additional constraints)
```

If you want a solution that is close, you can add slacks and minimize the sum of the squared errors:

```
 min ||s|| + ||t||
 F(x) = s
 G(x) = t
```

I use this approach quite a lot.

Comment: Hi Erwin many thanks for this new angle. What do you mean by “slacks”?. If I understand you correctly your minimization equation is the sum of squared errors of both equations, ie sum of a vector plus  a scalar? 
And F(x) =0 and G(x) =0 are added as constraints? The problem I ran into is that constraints for optimizations take scalars only and F(x) takes a vector. That was what I couldn’t get around.  Perhaps I misunderstood your setup. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: If we have say `F(x)=0` then a slack variable `F(x)-s=0` measures the difference between the l.h.s. `F(x)` and the r.h.s. 0. The name "slack" or "slack variable" is used a lot in optimization. I don't understand your statement that constraints only take scalar arguments. That is obviously not the case.

Comment: Many thanks Erwin. I will try to implement this today. I was under the misapprehension that constraints in optimization take only scalar arguments. I'll come back on this.  Groeten, L

Comment: Indeed, constraints need not be scalar. Rookie error. I've implemented the slacks and minimize the sum of squares etc.. That seems to work nicely. Trying out some of the optimization algorithms only one returns a meaningful result in the sense that it  satisfies the constraint F(x1,x2...xn)= [0,0,0..0]. However the objective function is not optimzed at all. And a warning is  given: "Singular Jacobian matrix. Using SVD decomposition to perform the factorizations.". Under SLSQP it also return that the Jacobian is singular.  Do you know what that is usually an indication of?

Comment: I have not much experience with SLSQP (my models tend to be large and sparse, and need more advanced solvers). One thing you can try is to use different starting points. Not sure what "Singular Jacobian matrix" is (Jacobians are typically not square, but may be SLSQP uses a different definition; it may be related to dependent rows. Usually, NLP solvers can handle this better.).

Comment: thanks for the pointer Erwin. I'm looking at the Gekko NLP solver suit. It might be a while before I come back on this, but I'll keep you posted. I think this is useful information for the forum. Possibly the answer is staring me in the face.